# how do i access GData api's(get map) in my application in iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

how do i access GData api's(get map) in my application ? 
     hey i tryed to add gdata.framework in my iphone application but it generate error and tell me in iphone how can i use this web service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can use [gdata-objective-client](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/).**

It can be compiled as a static library. Once you set it up in your application have a look at [example applications - MapSample](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/source/browse/#svn/trunk/Examples/MapsSample) that come with the library about how to access gdata map api.

Comment: I need to use in iphone app. The given sample is mac app. It is creating problem in iphone app.

Comment: There are instructions on how to use the library with iphone http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/wiki/BuildingTheLibrary - you just follow code examples and build it into your iphone application ...